# Node js and express js https setup issues with php

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am facing below different issues on chrome and mozilla.

> Mozilla:- **Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy
> disallows reading the remote resource at domain.com**
>
> Chrome:- **ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH**

I have checked a lot on this but didn't find solution.

**Here How I create keys on server**

```
openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 1024
openssl req -new -key server-key.pem -out server-csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server-csr.pem -signkey server-key.pem -out server-cert.pem
```

PHP File code:-

```
 <script>            
        var socket = io.connect( 'https://'+window.location.hostname+':3000' , {
        secure: true // for SSL
    });

        socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
            if(curkey == data.key)
            {
                $('#notif_audio')[0].play();
                $( "#tbids" ).html( data.message ).css('color', '#a94442');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Node file code:-

```
    var express = require('express');
     var app     = express();
    //var server  = require('https').createServer(app);
    var https = require("https");
    var fs = require("fs");

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("server-key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("server-cert.pem")
}

var server  = https.createServer(app, options);

var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;

io.set('origins', '*:*');

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
        io.sockets.emit( 'message', { 
            new_count_message: data.new_count_message,
            key: data.key
        });
    });
});
```

> On CLI, node server.js working fine without any error. Means there is
> no error in node file.

Note:- I have successfully setup this code on localhost with http.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please note I am working on live site. On localhost I have setup successfully with http.